# undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when add google map Sdk in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoapods

when i install google map with Cocoapods 
when build p .xcworkspace 
give me an error
linker command failed with exit code

my pod file

```
platform : ios, '12.1'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' 
target 'mapapp' do 
  pod 'GoogleMaps'  
 pod 'GooglePlaces' 
end
```

i attach picture

plese help me [image]

Comment: Please include your Pod file

Comment: @andlin added pod file  , what  it is the wrong?

Comment: I believe you need to upgrade to Xcode 11. Do a search for isPlatformVersionAtLeast.

Comment: @Don  my xcode is 10.1

Comment: I think your two options are to either upgrade to Xcode 11 to use the current GoogleMaps library or to use an earlier version of GoogleMaps that will work with Xcode 10.

Comment: @Don how write the old version in pod file?

Comment: You just use `pod 'GoogleMaps', 'versionNumber'`. Sorry, I'm not familiar with GoogleMaps versions, but it looks like the latest is 3.8.0. I did see this note on their site: "Developing an application with the Maps SDK for iOS requires at least Xcode 11.0"

Comment: @Don  thank for you it is work for me . i changed to 3.0.0  in xcode 10.1